# Team Foundation Server - Hide Collections?

Tags: tfs

I just setup a TFS 2012 server and was wondering if there is a way to hide collections between departments? So only IT would see the IT collections etc.? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove somebodies access to the collection they won't see it listed in the Connect to TFS dialog.